# How to add two XMLNS codes?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I already add one fb xmlnx code like below, and now I wana add another one also.

```
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'>
```

when I add like below, it shows error,

```
    <html 
xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
xmlns:fb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'>
```

can anyone tell me how to add both codes???

Comment: Try change namespace alias name: `xmlns:fb2='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'`

Comment: @gahcep xmlns:fb2='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'
    xmlns:ofb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'
both are not working, how could I change the name?? I need to approach two different links of "fb".

Comment: You could try an approach desribing in [XML Namespaces Explained](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/) article. See **Defining the Same Prefix for Multiple Namespaces** section.

Answer (score 3):

A General answer:

There is no way to "concatenate" namespaces, but you can give them different prefixes

```
    <html 
          xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
          xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'>
```

Then use fb:tag for facebook tags and og:tag for ogp.me tags

A specific answer:

The recommended use of Open Graph protocol is not via the xmlns attribute but via a prefix attribute ( http://ogp.me/ ) So the code that uses both, will look like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# [YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]: 
                  http://ogp.me/ns/apps/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[YOUR_APP_ID]" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:recipe" /> 
  ...
```

Example courtesy of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: xmlns:fb2='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'
    xmlns:ofb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'
both are not working, how could I change the name?? I need to approach two different links of "fb".

Comment: OG recommends using prefix attribute, look the updated answer